# Is there an elegant way of setting return type to a limited set of possible value types?

Tags: typescript

For example, if I have interfaces: Car, Motorcycle and Bicycle, with different structure, and I want to create a function like:
`getVehicle (vehicleType: string): Car | Motorcycle | Bicycle {}`
is there a way to more succinctly set the return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a type alias - but there's no more succinct way to declare the type ultimately.

```js
type Vehicle = Car | Motorcycle | Bicycle;

getVehicle (vehicleType: string): Vehicle {}
```

If it's a common function, you can type alias the entire function:

```js
type Vehicle = Car | Motorcycle | Bicycle;
type VehicleFetcher = (vehicleType: string) => Vehicle;

getVehicle: VehicleFetcher = (vehicleType) => {}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) you can find more information about using unions and type aliases.